# Why I can't access OKHttp Body?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I can output the **I / okhttp.OkHttpClient:**
structure as it appears in the pictures, but I cannot access it in any way. There have been many topics on this subject and it has been stated that this is the solution `response.body().string();` but when I write this code I get a **Syntax error** with `.string()`.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMZsV.png)
[Syntax-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXYYQ.png)

```
class RegisterPage : AppCompatActivity() {
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_page)
    button.setOnClickListener {
            val retrofit=
                    Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(getHttpClient()).baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL).build()
            val jsonPlaceholderApi=retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderApi::class.java)
            val userPost = Register(
                    name.text.toString(),
                    user.text.toString(),
                    pass.text.toString()
            )
            val call=jsonPlaceholderApi.sendRegister(userPost)

            call.enqueue(object : Callback<Void> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>, response: Response<Void>) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful){
                        println("asd")
                    }else{
                        println(response.body())
                    }

                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>, t: Throwable) {
                    println(t.printStackTrace())
                }

            })
        }
}
fun getHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
   // logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY


    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addInterceptor(logging).build()
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are confusing Retrofit and OkHttp Callback interfaces.  The string() method withs on Response.body() from an OkHttp Response, not Retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

This is Kotlin. I think you have to do it like this:

```
response.body()?.string()
```

Source: https://medium.com/@rohan.s.jahagirdar/android-http-requests-in-kotlin-with-okhttp-5525f879b9e5

Comment: i try but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The generic type of your `Response` is `Void`, you should change that to something like `String`, because the Void type dictates that it has no response.